# Invalid signature error when trying to generate request token in Pyramid oauth provider

Tags: python, oauth, provider, pyramid, consumer

I'm trying to generate a request token using `oauth2` in a Pyramid application for controlling access to an API I'm developing.  I'm stuck trying to verify my consumer key and secret working from [this example](http://philipsoutham.com/post/2172924723/two-legged-oauth-in-python).  On the Pyramid request_token endpoint I have the following:

```
@view_config(route_name = "api_request_token", request_method = "GET")
def api_request_token(request):
    auth_header = {}
    if ('Authorization' in request.headers):
        auth_header = {'Authorization': request.headers['Authorization']}

    req = oauth2.Request.from_request(
        request.method,
        request.url,
        headers = auth_header,
        query_string = request.query_string)

    try:
        oauth_server.verify_request(req, ConsumerKeySecret.getByConsumerKey(request.params.get('oauth_consumer_key')), None)
    except oauth2.Error, e:
        print e
    except KeyError, e:
        print e
    except Exception, e:
        print e
```

(`ConsumerKeySecret.getByConsumerKey` is a SQLAlchemy model classmethod that sets instance variables of `key` and `secret` for the given `key`.)

On the consumer side, again following the blog post mentioned earlier, I'm doing the following:

```
def build_request(url, method='GET'):
    params = {                                            
        'oauth_version': "1.0",
        'oauth_nonce': oauth2.generate_nonce(),
        'oauth_timestamp': int(time.time()),
        'oauth_signature_method': 'HMAC-SHA1',
    }
    consumer = oauth2.Consumer(key='b9085cb942dc427c92dd', secret='1735fd5b090381dcaf57')
    params['oauth_consumer_key'] = consumer.key
    req = oauth2.Request(method=method, url=url, parameters=params)
    signature_method = oauth2.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()
    req.sign_request(signature_method, consumer, None)
    return req

request = build_request("http://localhost:6543/api/01/request_token")
u = urllib2.urlopen(request.to_url())
```

The verification fails, however, with the following error:

`Invalid signature. Expected signature base string: GET&http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A6543%2Fapi%2F01%2Frequest_token&oauth_body_hash%3D2jmj7l5rSw0yVb%252FvlWAYkK%252FYBwk%253D%26oauth_body_hash%3D2jmj7l5rSw0yVb%252FvlWAYkK%252FYBwk%253D%26oauth_consumer_key%3Db9085cb942dc427c92dd%26oauth_consumer_key%3Db9085cb942dc427c92dd%26oauth_nonce%3D42023151%26oauth_nonce%3D42023151%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1310338562%26oauth_timestamp%3D1310338562%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26oauth_version%3D1.0`

I'm confused here however as each query string parameter appears twice in the "expected" signature.  What could be going wrong?

If that's an easy question to answer, I have a follow-up: once I've actually verified the request, how do I generate the request tokens?  The `oauth2` library is a little sketchy on documentation regarding this point, and most examples out there seem to be geared towards implementing consumers, rather then creating providers as well.

Thanks!

**Update**  Responding to my own question to give what I think is an answer.  From this [bug report](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/issues/58) for `oauth2`, it would appear that the inclusion of the `oauth_body_hash` parameter was messing up my signature verification since I was using `GET`.  Changing it to `POST` fixed the problem.  Strange that this would occur anyway given that I'm also *testing* with this library.

And to answer the second part, I believe you can just generate any key/secret pair that is random and long enough.  I've seen people split up sha1 hashes of some random source into two 20 character parts.  You can then us `oauth2.Token` to automatically create the URL that you can then use in your `authorize_token` step.

Of course, if I'm wrong on any of this be sure to let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds exactly like a problem I ran into, but I came to a different (possible) solution.

It looks like all the query string parameters are being included twice, which is described in this bug report: https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/issues/21

Stripping the query string parameters as the issue described fixed it for me.